# Is filterPushdown a setting for PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Came across Hortonwork's blog post advocating for predicate push-down [in this post](http://hortonworks.com/blog/bringing-orc-support-into-apache-spark/).

I can't find it in Spark 1.4 documentation though (that's the version I'm using). Do I need to worry about setting this to false, or is it already a native setting? If I can change this, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Predicate pushdown is part of the catalyst optimization of spark. This happens automatically.

For example, let's say you are creating a dataframe from an SQL server and then you are doing a filter on it. It would probably be better performance if the filtering were to be done in the SQL server instead of in spark (to reduce the amount of traffic on the network). Spark's catalyst engine would recognize that JDBC source supports predicate pushdown and would reorganize your expression to do so.

In the specific example of the article, it only says that the ORC source supports predicate pushdown for specific cases (i.e. when it has builtin indexes).

This is not something you need to worry about in 99.9% of the cases, it will just improve performance behind the scenes.

Comment: Okay, say that I have a dataframe based on a flat file. Then I want to filter it based on data that is greater than a timestamp, for example yesterday morning `01-13-2017 08:00:00`. Would the predicate pushdown be applied automatically when I do the filtering? This is all within Pyspark of course

Comment: The depends on the type of file. ORC would be yes. Parquet might also be true (at least it will push column selection and also if you used partitionBy when writing). If it is other formats, probably not. The file format must support indexing and it's interface implementation should support this as well.